# Reading a basic file from resources directory with spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have no clue why in the world this would be causing me this much grief but it is. How can I just very simply grab my txt file from uber jar packaged resources directory when I run spark-submit and pass it to a spark.read? Yes. IDE is simple and works. But running with spark-submit is plaguing me with the good old fashioned:

```
Path does not exist: file:/opt/spark/jars/<myjar>.jar!/datasets/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt
```

My folder structure is very standard:

```
src
  main
    resources
      sample_kmeans_data.txt
```

My very vanilla loader:

```
val kmeansData = 
  getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("datasets/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt").getPath
val dataset: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("libsvm")
  .load(kmeansData)
dataset.show
```

I have also confirmed `datasets` folder at root level after extracting jar and I've tried many different versions of classLoader, all leading to same error. Lastly, reading the file as a stream or input buffer without spark works fine and can clearly get to the file from jar with spark submit. I'm getting tripped up by what the loader in spark needs as just an input path from the jar.

Comment: If I remember correctly, spark-submit is like a deployment function.You use this to deploy your function to a cluster right? I would guess your problem is either : a) You haven't configured your local cluster right. Either so you're not connecting to it correctly. b) You're trying to connect to a remote cluster that you don't have access to. Because of the file error, my guess it is a.

Comment: @GamingFelix. you are right. I've been working off of object storage for so long I forgot the requirements for a local file from a distributed file system like hdfs I used to do. I was hoping to just implement a quick sample test for reading a file from the packaged jar. I guess I can just grab something from object storage and make my life a whole lot easier. thanks.

Comment: no problems! Was just guessing :D

Comment: If you are using sbt version 1.2.8, there is a known bug there. Try to upgrade.